# npm install command - please explain

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am starting to learn React Native and I am very new to npm package manager.  I read that npm can install packages localy or globaly but I am trying to understand what does that mean.
I am reading this page https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally, can someone explain to me what does this mean please.

> If you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node.js' require, then you want to install locally, which is npm install's default behavior. On the other hand, if you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally.

Since I am very new to npm, React Native, Node (never used it), I am confused by the very first sentence in this quote.  What does it mean "my own module?

If I want to use CRNA, I guess, I would have to install it globally?

If I am to install a package, say CRNA locally or globally, where do I see it installed on my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between local and global install is that local install puts it into the `node_modules` directory of your project (this is what is referred to as "your own module") while global puts it into a system directory (the exact location depends on your OS, on OSX it should be `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`).

Basically:

- Local install ties the installed module to your project: other projects on your computer do not get it but if your project is copied to another computer the module will be installed there too
- global install ties it to your computer: you can use it on all of
  your projects on your computer but if your project is copied to
  another computer the installed module will not be there

And yes, CRNA should be installed globally as it is a general tool not a project's library dependence.

Answer (score 1):

When you install package globally `npm install -g <package name>` modules drops in `{prefix}/lib/node_modules`.

Locally - `npm install <package name>` - drops package in the current working directory.

If you are going to `require` module in your project you have to install it locally.

If you want to run in from command line you need to install it globally.

If you need more extenden explanation [take a look](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)

Answer (score 1):

> Since I am very new to npm, React Native, Node (never used it), I am confused by the very first sentence in this quote. What does it mean "my own module?

If you have `package.json` file, then everything in the same folder is treated as "module". You add dependencies to it by doing `npm install --save foo` (`--save` option adds it under `dependencies` in your `package.json`).

> If I want to use CRNA, I guess, I would have to install it globally?

Not sure what "CRNA" is. But general rule is that mostly everything (libraries...) are installed locally. Which means that they are added to your `package.json` and installed in same folder under `node_modules`.

Only case when you want to install something globally (can be added to `package.json` but is NOT installed in the same folder under `node_modules` but probably in your home directory), by doing `npm install --global bar` (`--global` installs it globally). Is when tool (not library) is project independent, as you can access it from everywhere. Something like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

---

TLDR:

- **Local** are dependencies (libraries) installed in same folder and (usually) added in your `package.json` as dependencie.
- **Global** are tools installed in your user home folder and (usually) NOT added in your `package.json` as dependencie.

Answer (score 1):

Let first start with how nodejs finds package.

Suppose you have some folder structure like-

```
root
    -pixel
       -project1
       -project2
```

So, if your are working on `project1` and required some npm package, nodejs tries to find a folder named `node_modules` in current directory. If fails, it goes parent(pixel folder) and tries to find `node_modules` and goes recursively upto root(which is global).

So, if there any package installed globally, you don't need to install it in your current working directory.

So, why don't we install all packages globally? Isn't it saves our harddisk memory?

Yes, true. But as npm packages are updating and changing its version everytime, its necessary to use specific package in your current working package to avoid collusion.

Then how global packages is useful? 
Its good idea to install some cli packages to run directly from command line i.e `webpack` to easy our task.